# Problem in building my own module in omnetpp

Tags: c++, linker, g++, ld

I'm trying to write an application using the UDP module included 
in the inetmanet framework in omnetpp. The problem is that the files that I have to include don't get included in the linking phase.

The errors are:

opp_makemake

```
bedo@ethereal:~/omnetpp/samples/Basic-Broadcast-Simulation$ opp_makemake --deep -f -I../inet-sommer/src/transport/contract -I../inet-sommer/src/networklayer/contract -I../inet-sommer/src/base
Creating Makefile in /home/bedo/omnetpp/samples/Basic-Broadcast-Simulation...
Makefile created, running "make depend" to add dependencies...
opp_makedep -Y --objdirtree -I../inet-sommer/src/transport/contract -I../inet-sommer/src/networklayer/contract -I../inet-sommer/src/base -I. -Igcc-debug -Igcc-debug/src -Igcc-debug/src/flooding -Isimulations -Isimulations/bitmaps -Isimulations/results -Isrc -Isrc/flooding -f Makefile -P\$O/ --   ./*.cc gcc-debug/*.cc gcc-debug/src/*.cc gcc-debug/src/flooding/*.cc simulations/*.cc simulations/bitmaps/*.cc simulations/results/*.cc src/*.cc src/flooding/*.cc
```

make

```
bedo@ethereal:~/omnetpp/samples/Basic-Broadcast-Simulation$ make
g++ -c -g -Wall -fno-stack-protector    -DHAVE_PCAP -DXMLPARSER=libxml -DWITH_PARSIM -DWITH_NETBUILDER  -I../inet-sommer/src/transport/contract -I../inet-sommer/src/networklayer/contract -I../inet-sommer/src/base -I. -Igcc-debug -Igcc-debug/src -Igcc-debug/src/flooding -Isimulations -Isimulations/bitmaps -Isimulations/results -Isrc -Isrc/flooding -I/home/bedo/omnetpp/include -o out/gcc-debug//src/flooding/Flooding.o src/flooding/Flooding.cc
src/flooding/Flooding.cc: In member function ‘virtual void Flooding::handleLowerMsg(cMessage*)’:
src/flooding/Flooding.cc:82: warning: unused variable ‘m’
g++ -Wl,--export-dynamic  -Wl,-rpath,/home/bedo/omnetpp/lib -Wl,-rpath,. -o out/gcc-debug//Basic-Broadcast-Simulation  out/gcc-debug//src/flooding/Flooding.o  -Wl,--whole-archive  -Wl,--no-whole-archive -L"/home/bedo/omnetpp/lib/gcc" -L"/home/bedo/omnetpp/lib" -u _tkenv_lib -lopptkenvd -loppenvird -lopplayoutd -u _cmdenv_lib -loppcmdenvd -loppenvird  -loppsimd -ldl -lstdc++ 
out/gcc-debug//src/flooding/Flooding.o: In function `Flooding::setupLowerLayer()':
/home/bedo/omnetpp/samples/Basic-Broadcast-Simulation/src/flooding/Flooding.cc:50: undefined reference to `UDPControlInfo::UDPControlInfo()'
/home/bedo/omnetpp/samples/Basic-Broadcast-Simulation/src/flooding/Flooding.cc:52: undefined reference to `UDPSocket::generateSocketId()'
out/gcc-debug//src/flooding/Flooding.o: In function `Flooding::sendMessage()':
/home/bedo/omnetpp/samples/Basic-Broadcast-Simulation/src/flooding/Flooding.cc:101: undefined reference to `UDPControlInfo::UDPControlInfo()'
/home/bedo/omnetpp/samples/Basic-Broadcast-Simulation/src/flooding/Flooding.cc:103: undefined reference to `IPAddress::ALL_HOSTS_MCAST'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/gcc-debug//Basic-Broadcast-Simulation] Error 1
bedo@ethereal:~/omnetpp/samples/Basic-Broadcast-Simulation$
```

I really don't know why they get included, and my module compile fine, but in the linking phase I get "undefined reference".

Any idea?

Comment: Unless there's an omnetpp expert here, this will require some back-and-forth. The makefiles are not handling the dependencies right, so that the linker doesn't link the UDP code (or at least not the part of it that `Flooding` needs). You could start by finding the source file containing e.g. `UDPControlInfo()`, and finding out if it's been compiled into an object file, and if so whether that object file's been linked into a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I modified the makefile in the root directory to a simpler one, leaving all the compile and linking duties to the src's makefile.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can run `nm` on on all libraries you link with to see which library undefined symbols like this:

```
nm liboppcmdenvd.(so/a) | c++filt | grep UDPControlInfo
```

(`c++filt` demangles C++ symbols).

Library that requires the symbol will get output something like (`U` for Undefined):

```
00000000007f90a0 U UDPControlInfo
```

Library that defines/has the symbol will get output something like:

```
00000000007f90a0 T UDPControlInfo
```

This can be `T` or `t`

Of course, libraries you link with are indicated by arguments with starting by `-l`:

```
-lopptkenvd -loppenvird -lopplayoutd -u _cmdenv_lib -loppcmdenvd -loppenvird  
liboppcmdenvd liboppenvird  liboppsimd libUDPControlInfo
```